# Set two (or more) variables to another variable PHP

Tags: php, variables, echo

I need to assign two other variables to a variable.

Basically, I need to do something like this:

```
$gameName = $jackpot->gameName = $jackpot->MachineName;
echo $gameName;
```

Both `$jackpot->gameName` and `$jackpot->MachineName` return a "text" (a name) from two different parsed XML files.

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: How exactly is the variable even suppose to hold two different values?

Comment: Do you just want the strings concatenated?  `$gameName = $jackpot->gameName . ' ' . $jackpot->MachineName;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods you can follow based on your requirement.

You can hold your data in an array.

```
$gameName = Array($jackpot->gameName,$jackpot->MachineName);
```

You can concat the two variables and store it in a new variable.

```
$gameName = $jackpot->gameName." ".$jackpot->MachineName;
```

Comment: I wouldn't advice option 2 at all. What if there's a space in one of the values? Then you have something like `foo bar blah` what are the two variables?

Comment: Yes, first one is the most recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array to hold the values:

```
$gameName = Array($jackpot->gameName,$jackpot->MachineName);
```

However, if you try to `echo` this you will just get `Array`. You would need to either `print_r()` it, or `echo $gameName[0]." / ".$gameName[1];`